# GIT push Unauthorized when SSH keys already added

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I don't have any branch permission set, I also already added public key into BitBucket SSH settings.

```
┌──[forge@app]──[~/app]                                                                  
└── git status                                                                               
On branch master                                                                             
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.                                        
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)                                             
nothing to commit, working directory clean                                                   
┌──[forge@app]──[~/app]                                                                  
└── git push origin master                                                                   
Unauthorized                                                                                 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                                

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.                                                                   
┌──[forge@app]──[~/app]                                                                  
└──
```

I kept getting

> Unauthorized
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first your [current remote URL](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/change-the-remote-url-to-your-repository-794212774.html):

```
cd ~/app
git remote -v
```

It should be like `git@bitbucket.org:<me>/<myproject>`

Then check the output of:

```
ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org
```

You will see if you are correctly authenticated.